# How to add suggested post

Tags: python, django

how do I add a Suggested post after my first two post. For example, Post Post... Suggested post... Post Post.

```
def home(request):
    all_images = Image objects.filter(imageuploader_profile=request.user, active=True)
    context={'all_images':all_images}

#my post here
{% for post in all_images %}
{{ post.username }}
{% if post.profile_pic %}
<img src = "{{....}}">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Isn't `{% if forloop.counter == 3 %}Suggested post here{% endif %}` enough for your need?

Comment: @parrizaans.. How do I add the forloop counter to my own template (question). Can you help me edit my template(question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current counter of a forloop in Django templates. Having an if statement on `forloop.counter` will resolve your requirement. By using that, your template would be like:

```
{% for post in all_images %}
    {{ post.username }}
    {% if post.profile_pic %}
        <img src = "{{....}}">
    {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}
        {{ suggested_post.username }}
        {% if suggested_post.profile_pic %}
            <img src = "{{....}}">
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The above will solve your problem but in order to avoid having duplicate code, you can have a tiny template that renders a post. Then include that for each post or suggested post.

Then you will have `post.html`:

```
{{ suggested_post.username }}
{% if suggested_post.profile_pic %}
    <img src = "{{....}}">
{% endif %}
```

And all_posts template will be something like:

```
{% for post in all_images %}
    {% include 'post.html' %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}
        {% include 'post.html' with post=suggested_post %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```